# Finding upper bound for sum

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

My question:

> Show that an upper bound for the sum $$\sum_1^{10}\frac{r+1}{r^2+2r+2}$$ is equal to $\ln 61$

My attempt:

Upper bound is equal to
$$\int_1^{11}\frac{r+1}{r^2+2r+2} dr$$

$$\int_1^{11}\frac{r+1}{r^2+2r+2} dr = \frac 12 [\ln|r^2+2r+2|]_1^{11}$$
$$=\frac 12 \ln 145 - \ln 5$$
$$=\ln(\sqrt {29})$$

Something's wrong here and I can't work out what. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Evaluate the integral over $r=0$ to $10$

Comment: *An* upper bound not the upper bound.

Comment: @MarcusStuhr Hang on a second, doesn't that give $\ln \sqrt {61}$ rather than $\ln 61$?

Comment: Yes -- but $\ln (\sqrt{61})= \frac{1}{2} \ln (61) \lt \ln (61) $